# Difference between apache kafka and amazon sqs

Tags: apache-kafka, amazon-sqs

what are the main differences between them and when to use kafka or sqs

I read about them but not able to identify the difference between them. As I haves used kafka for streaming data. One difference is that sqs is managed by amazon and for kafka we have to host it.

Answer (score 0):

The main difference is that Kafka is a persistent log, distributed by partitions that many consumers can seek/rewind freely. It does not remove messages after consumption. It also uses its own unique TCP protocol.

> for kafka we have to host it.

False. See Amazon MSK (Managed Streaming Kafka)

Answer (score 0):

Kafka follows a distributed publish/subscribe messaging model, where messages are organized into topics and multiple consumers can subscribe to those topics. It provides a streaming platform with high throughput and low latency. SQS, on the other hand, follows a traditional queuing model, where messages are sent to a queue and processed by a single consumer at a time.

Kafka retains messages for a configurable amount of time or based on storage limits, allowing consumers to replay historical data. SQS, by default, retains messages for up to 14 days, but once consumed, the messages are removed from the queue and cannot be replayed.

There are several managed Kafka services available that you can use instead of self-hosting Apache Kafka.

1. Amazon Managed Streaming for Apache Kafka (MSK)
2. Confluent Cloud
3. Azure Event Hubs for Apache Kafka
4. Google Cloud Pub/Sub with Kafka